# How to use condition with query builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have orders table which contains `status, paymode, pay_status` column

I want to get order if `paymode` is `cod` then `pay_status` `unconfirmed` can get 
and 
if `paymode` is `payu` then `pay_status` only `confirmed` can get

Here I tried with `whereRaw`

```
$orders = Order::whereHas('products', function (Builder $query) use ($seller) {
            $query->where('seller_id', $seller->id);
        })
            ->whereRaw('IF (`paymode` = `payu`, `pay_status` = `confirmed`)')
            ->paginate(25);
```

but it's not working

Comment: paymode ,pay_status this in the same table?

Comment: paymode is payment mode cod or payu and pay_status is confirmed unconfirmed or failed both are different column

Comment: yes I understand but this column in same table ?

Comment: yes both column in same table @RushikeshGanesh

Comment: $orders = Order::whereHas('products', function (Builder $query) use ($seller) {
            $query->where('seller_id', $seller->id);
        })->whereRaw('paymode = ? AND pay_status = ?', ['payu','confirmed'])
          ->paginate(25);

Comment: try like this hope it will work

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== ? AND pay_status == ?' at line 1

Comment: yes by mistake i added ==

Comment: i edited please check now

Comment: its working when paymode is payu and i also want paymode is cod and unconfimed come @RushikeshGanesh

Comment: add or condition in it will work for cod and unconfimed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like this also for multiple conditions

```
 $orders = Order::whereHas('products', 
    function (Builder $query) use ($seller) { 
         $query->where('seller_id', $seller->id); 
    })->whereRaw('paymode = ? AND pay_status = ?', ['payu','confirmed']) 
      ->orWhereRaw('paymode = ? AND pay_status = ?', ['cod','unconfimed ']) 
    ->paginate(25);
```